# Identify this plant from the Netherlands with big white flower

Tags: botany, species-identification

The picture was taken today in the Netherlands. Can you identify this plant species?

[image]

Comment: From the leaves and flower it could be a clematis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @skymningen thought, this is a Clematis. However, the only wild Clematis in the Netherlands is *Clematis vitalba*, that has much smaller flowers (about 2 cm diameter) see "Heukels' Flora van Nederland" (the official Dutch flora) and [here](http://www.soortenbank.nl/soorten.php?soortengroep=flora_nl_v2&id=791&menuentry=soorten).

So you have photographed a plant that "escaped" from a garden. Most garden Clematis are hybrids from Chinese or Japanese origen. As there are about 300 species and new hybrids constantly being produced, the likelyhood of finding it's name is low. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis